# display post_tag_links in tags/show.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

hi i'm making bulletin board system with acts_as_taggable_on in rails.

i have question, how to display post_tag_links in tags/show.html.erb.

my code is below

**tags_controller.rb**

```
def show
 @tag=ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.find_by(name: params[:name])
 @posts = Post.tagged_with(@tag.name)
end
```

**tags show.html.erb**

```
<h1><%= @tag.name %></h1><%= link_to "タグ一覧",tags_path %>
<div><%= render @posts %></div>
```

**post.rb**

```
 acts_as_taggable_on :tags
 acts_as_taggable
 after_validation :save_tags

 def save_tags
  array = self.check_taggable_word(self.title)
  self.tag_list.add(array, parse: true)
 end

 def tag_lists
  tag_lists = self.tag_list
 end

 def check_taggable_word(text)
  ary = Array.new
  nm = Natto::MeCab.new
  nm.parse(text) do |n|
   ary<<n.surface
  end 
  tags = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.pluck(:name) 
  return ary & tags
 end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'static_pages#home'
  get '/about' => 'static_pages#about'
  get '/contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  resources :categories do
   resources :posts
  end
  resources :posts do
   resources :comments
   resources :tags
  end
  get 'tags/:name' => 'tags#show'
  resources :tags, only: [:index, :show]
 end
```

Additional info
**posts_controller.rb**

```
def create
category_id = params[:post][:category_id]
if category_id.present? && Category.find_by(id: category_id)
  @category = Category.find_by(id: category_id)
else
  @post = Post.new(
      :title  => params[:post][:title],
      :name   => params[:post][:name]
    )
  @post.valid?
  render :action => "new" and return 
end

@post = Post.post_create(post_params)
@post.ip = request.remote_ip

if @post.name.present?
else
  @post.name = “no-name”
end

respond_to do |format|
  if @post.save

    format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: ‘done’ }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Comment: i did your code and then this error displayed  https://gyazo.com/55fd8f29114d1ecedb0e16b3ef43149a

Comment: thank you Fabrizio! i'm japanese student, and just started to learn coding 2 months ago:) I wanna write code more hard:)

Comment: thank you!!! i just added my posts_controller.rb above!

Comment: thank you so much Fabrizio!! i will try first:)

Comment: yes i also do not know... is it necessary to make 
Parent-child relationship between Post and Tag??

Answer (score 0):

### Implementing Act-as-taggable-on

https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on#tag-cloud-calculations

Include in your `post.rb` model or in your `user.rb` model

```
class Post
 acts_as_taggable_on :tags
end
```

Include in your `posts_controller` or in your `user_controller` the following strong params

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def user_params
    params.require(:posts).permit(:tag_list) ## Rails 4 strong params usage
  end
end
```

The **important** test that everything is working by creating tags.

```
@post = Post.new
```

Add a tag to your new @post

```
@post.tag_list.add("history")
@post.tag_list.add("england")
@post.save
```

Check the tags

```
@post.tag_list
@post.tags
```

This should be the expected output, if there is some problem in the tag creation you need to stop and fix it. The tagging count should be 1 if this tags are used just in this @post.

```
=> [#<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 1, name: "history", taggings_count: 1>,
 #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 2, name: "england", taggings_count: 1>]
```

### Implementing Tag Clouds

You would like to have on the show page of your post, a list of the tags links for that post redirecting to a separate page, that displays all posts with that tag. This functionality can be implemented with tag_cloud

For example, in the case of @post before created. The post#show of @post will have 2 tags "history, england,", if we select "history" link we will be redirected to a new page with links to all "history" posts.

The first step is understanding that this will be in the `posts#show` action of `posts_controller`. In this action we need to implement the following code.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @tags = Post.tag_counts_on(:tags)
  end
end
```

Know you will have to check that @tags get filled, so in your rails console do the following (I tested it and it return the following). If it is empty it will not work.
    @tags = Post.tag_counts_on(:tags)

```
=> [#<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag:0x00000006bb85e0 id: 6, name: "javascript", taggings_count: 4>,
 #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag:0x00000006bb84a0 id: 5, name: "html", taggings_count: 6>,
 #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag:0x00000006bb8220 id: 18, name: "java", taggings_count: 1>,
 #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag:0x00000006ba7ee8 id: 4, name: "css", taggings_count: 6>]
```

Then in your view posts/show.html.erb you will include the following code:
This code will loop @tags in a variable tag and create link to a new screen that we will configure with the action => :tag in the same controller.

```
<% @tags.each do |tag| %>
  <%= link_to tag.name, { :action => :tag, :id => tag.name } %>
<% end %>
```

Now you should test if the functionality work, but probably to see the :tag action you will need to create it, so in posts_controller create a tag action.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def tag
    @tag = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.find_by(name: params[:name])
    @posts = Post.tagged_with(@tag.name)
  end
end
```

Test it in console

```
@tag = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.find_by(name: "javascript")

=> #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag:0x000000069c1fc0 id: 6, name: "javascript", taggings_count: 4>
```

Then in the view you will need to show those post.

```
<%= @tag.name %>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
 <%= post.name %>
 <%= post.desctiption %>
 <%= etc... %>
<% end %>
```

Then configure the routing, for example the show action should not be a problem if you have in `routes.rb` resource :posts`,but you should configure the :tag action.

GET `posts/:id/tag` => 'posts#tag'`

We should make some editing of this discussion. We have written too many comments so you can delete them if you want and if some error message comes out you can write a new comment. Also If you have any problem the best way is to just edit your question and make there an explanation.

I did not use any more the following view, but you can also try with this one, but I do not have idea of what tag_cloud tag is. I think it is included in the module ActsAsTaggableOn::TagsHelper

```
   <% tag_cloud(@skills, %w(css1 css2 css3 css4)) do |skill, css_class| %>
      <%= link_to skill.name, { :action => :skill, :id => skill.name }, :class => css_class %>
    <% end %>
```

This is the module

```
module PostsHelper
  include ActsAsTaggableOn::TagsHelper
end
```

Comment: hi Fabrizio. I tried... however my tag did not count 'taggings_count', i am not sure why. here is what i checked in my console.

@tag
=> #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 1, name: "TAG-1", taggings_count: 0>

Comment: hello, i just added that def. but this error is still displayed. https://gyazo.com/eb0b57688b76a5d441c7aa6fae130c89

Comment: i did not save tag yet after self.tag_list.add in save_tags method at post.rb.
what do you think??? if i add self.method after self.tag_list.add, then save method will implement as loop ....

Comment: i tried above code and then this error was displayed...https://gyazo.com/4ff3eedaac40e8c8019f2363349ac38b

Comment: oh sorry... i forgot that...

and then this error was displayed https://gyazo.com/24034fcd480b6d67e3a33521e2ae9160

Comment: and then if i delete <%= puts tag %>, this error was displayed....
https://gyazo.com/4dbe8b5ad531e601cd430eb9e4865d8e

Comment: hi Fabrizio, ummm i still have error https://gyazo.com/53448038d011e435f9d85d0ec490a8a0

Comment: but if i change "<% tag_cloud(@tags," to "<% tag_cloud(@tag," then error was displayed.
https://gyazo.com/152478850e620a93b37630f5cae19e9f

Comment: @tokyo.a I updated my post and I am deleting some of the comments as they may not be relevant for those that will read this post in the future.

Comment: hello Febrizio, i tried your latest code and then this error is displayed..... https://gyazo.com/040a008aef83b6b8b4ad0413ceb5418b

Comment: @tokyo.a Hello, I edited my answer with completely new instructions. Please review them and try to fix the problem thanks fabrizio. Also make some review of the comment and delete those that are not useful, otherwise you will be downvoted from the admins and the discussion may be closed